# name 'eyes_roi' is not defined, OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter

I am trying to perform a driver drowsiness detection which requires scanning faces and eyes. But I am getting this error that I cannot solve. I have checked it several times. The error says: *name 'eyes_roi' is not defined* even though it is defined.
Please help if you can. Here is the code snippet:

```
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades
                                    + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
                                    )

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

if not cap.isOpened():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError('Cannot open front camera!')

while True:
    (ret, frame) = cap.read()
    eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades
            + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)

    for (x, y, w, h) in eyes:
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + h]
        roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + h]
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        eyess = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        if len(eyess) == 0:
            print('Eyes not detected!')
        else:
            for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyess:
                eyes_roi = roi_color[ey:ey + eh, ex:ex + eh]

    final_image = cv2.resize(eyes_roi, (244, 244))
    final_image = np.expand_dims(final_image, axis=0)
    final_image = final_image / 255.0

    pred = new_model.predict(final_image)
    if pred.any() > 0:
        status = 'Driver Active'
    else:
        status = 'Driver Drowsy'

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print(faceCascade.empty())
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

    cv2.putText(
        frame,
        status,
        (55, 55),
        font,
        3,
        (0, 0, 255),
        2,
        cv2.LINE_4,
        )
    cv2.imshow('Driver Drowsiness', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It is possible that the code never reaches the `eyes_roi = ...` statement, either because `eyes` is empty or `eyess` is empty. In that case, `eyes_roi` would be undefined.

Comment: `if len(eyess) == 0` if that if statement is true, `eyes_roi` is not defined.

Comment: Agree with the above comments. If there is no detection, you will never reach the variable. Apart from that, I recommend you to load the eye model as initialization and not in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

rather then this

```
eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
```

use this

```
eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
```

try changing this